# How to Stream audio from website C#

Tags: c#, audio

what i am trying to do is stream audio from this site (http://www.dubstep.net/track/5436). which at this point im not to sure if it is possible to stream the audio from the site. 
i have tried to use naudio with this code

```
public static void PlayMp3FromUrl(string url)
{
using (Stream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (Stream stream = WebRequest.Create(url)
        .GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
        int read;
        while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }

    ms.Position = 0;
    using (WaveStream blockAlignedStream =
        new BlockAlignReductionStream(
            WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(
                new Mp3FileReader(ms))))
    {
        using (WaveOut waveOut = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback()))
        {
            waveOut.Init(blockAlignedStream);
            waveOut.Play();                        
            while (waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing )                        
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

but since this site doesn't have a .mp3 after it this will not work..

Comment: Looks like you're out of luck. The stream is being played by an embedded Flash Player (probably as an RTMP stream) from SoundCloud. I think you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: http://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/stream-and-download